# Additional variable for wordpress comments?

Tags: wordpress, textbox, comments, append

I'm stuck! I need an additional variable in Wordpress comments. I have already made a field for it, let's call it "hometown".

```
            <p><input type="text" name="hometown" id="hometown" size="22" />
<label for="url"><small>Whats your hometown?</small></label></p>
```

This value needs to be stored and echo'ed when needed in comments loop. Is there any way to do this?

If it's not possible, a simpler method that appends #hometown value to the comment textbox's itself could do. The script I tried for appending text also doesn't work :

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var txt = document.querySelector("#hometown").value; 
    document.querySelector("#comment").value+= txt;
});
```

Please help me asap! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this out, it might be the thing you want.
[click here](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/08/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but ''a bit too much'', I need faster and simpler solution

Comment: Well it's a plugin and with minor modifications in it you could simply add your desired custom field in your comment form